# Вывод на экран большого текста

Tags: c++

Помогите пожалуйста, я уже запарился искать, пытаться делать, уже огромное время потратил в пустую.

Думал писать функцию, но просто знаний видимо не хватает

выводить текст через

```
cout << "  123 \   123\ " << endl
```

На следующую строку - муторно.

Есть ли способ для вывода на экран огромного текста?
(не читать с файла)

На пример предложений 10-20

Что-то по типу

```
print("
Предложение 1
Предложение 2
Предложение 3
Предложение 4

");
```

Умоляю, подскажите

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal

Вам нужен вариант 5 (если считать с 0)

Comment: @gbg Мне кажется, все-таки шестой :)

Comment: @HarryfromKiev, я от нуля считаю, привычка уже (дурная)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для таких задач обычно используют [цикл](https://www.w3schools.com/cpp/cpp_for_loop.asp), а не функцию.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int
main ()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
      cout << "String " << i << "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
printf(R"(
Предложение 1
Предложение 2
Предложение 3
Предложение 4
 
)");
```

Может кому понадобится, проблема решена